# require my modules in just one place

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, package

i would like to know the pros and cons of using one file to require all my node_modules dependencies and my own modules.

For example, one file called 'dependencies'

```
var dependencies = {
 node: {
   utils: require('utils')
 },
 own: {
  controllers: require('path/to/controllers')
 }
};
```

I don't see anyone doing this. Why??
Thanks.

Comment: Because usually you don't want to reach your dependencies through another object. I.e. `dependencies.node.utils...` vs `utils...`

Comment: but you want avoid require 50 modules in one file, no?

Comment: You mean you want to keep a file with all your dependencies so all your modules work with them? Since each module has it's own scope then unless you make them global you can't. It's better if each module has knowledge of their own dependencies.

Comment: Well, I was wrong in my last comment. Making them global is not the only way, you could just have a dependencies module. But again, it's better if your modules just know about their respective dependencies.

Comment: I agree with MinusFour, just be explicit, you don't really gain anything by splitting your dependencies out. If you have a dependency that shows up in many places, you can (a) globalize it by adding it to the `process` object, which I do not suggest or (b) use a dependecy injection pattern on the modules you would like to use the shared module in... here's an example https://gist.github.com/allthetime/d5cada9625f52b8f7c26 this can be pretty useful in some cases where you are trying to split a complicated module up into a few different files